# Change cell dimension in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

It may sound trivial, but I cannot figure this out:I have a (6x1) cell and want to convert it into (1x6). how can I do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `myCell = myCell.';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have cell (1x6), for example

```
J = {[4],[4],[4 5], [3 4 5], [], []}
```

and we can transpose

```
J'
```

we get cell (6x1).